# Ignore mouse drag over a QGraphicsObject

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget

I have a simple QRectF that I've put in a class that inherits from QGraphicsObject. I want the area of this rect to pass through mouse drag events. i.e. right now, I have click and drag moving the rect. However, I need that event sent to the background where I need to select multiple items (which is possible by default). Setting the attribute WA_TransparentForMouseEvents seems perfect for this, but as I understand, this only for QWidget.

```
class GraphicsItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self._box = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (self._box.contains(event.pos()):
            # set event transparency here
```

Is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: better create minimal working code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [`QGraphicsItem.shape()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape) for your item. I don't know what your GraphicsItem looks like but here is a general example. The other item can be selected from inside the `self._box` region.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class GraphicsItem(QGraphicsObject):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._box = QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.setFlags(self.ItemIsSelectable | self.ItemIsMovable)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(-100, -50, 300, 200)

    def shape(self):
        area = QPainterPath()
        area.addRect(self.boundingRect())
        box = QPainterPath()
        box.addRect(self._box)
        return area - box

    def paint(self, painter, *args):
        painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0, 180))
        painter.drawPath(self.shape())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    scene = QGraphicsScene(-200, -150, 500, 400)
    rect = scene.addRect(30, 30, 30, 30, Qt.black, Qt.red)
    rect.setFlags(rect.ItemIsSelectable | rect.ItemIsMovable)
    scene.addItem(GraphicsItem())

    view = QGraphicsView(scene)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Or if you specifically wanted to reimplement the mouse event handlers:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    event.ignore() if event.pos() in self._box else super().mousePressEvent(event)
```